# Control panel icons list

Tags: control-panel

Is there any list of icons used in control panel avaible? These ones that are displayed using webfont `Craft.woff`.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, you can look at the icon font [as an SVG](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/craftcms/cms/99e6774a627163f6f8a4d67f4dca12cc2f06a340/src/web/assets/cp/src/fonts/Craft.svg) (be sure to use the View Source)

Or look at [CP Nav](https://github.com/verbb/cp-nav/blob/37d71db5c5a1c9c8347d6e082588e4ca3ea46d12/src/templates/_includes/navigation-hud.html#L60-L144) which has them a little more accessible.